# Performance in database design

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-design, overhead, table-structure

I have to implement a testing platform. My database needs the following tables: `Students`, `Teachers`, `Admins`, `Personnel` and others. I would like to know if it's more efficient to have the `FirstName` and `LastName` in each of these tables, or to have another table, `Persons`, and each of the other table to be linked to this one with `PersonID`.

Personally, I like it this way, although trickier to implement, because I think it's cleaner, especially if you look at it from the object-oriented point of view.  Would this add an unnecessary overhead to the database?

Don't know if it helps to mention I would like to use SQL Server and ADO.NET Entity Framework.

Comment: [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've explicitly mentioned OO and that you're using EntityFramework, perhaps its worth approaching the problem instead from how the framework is intended to work - rather than just building a database structure and then trying to model it?

[Entity Framework Code First Inheritance : Table Per Hierarchy and Table Per Type](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/393228/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Inheritance-Table-Per) is a nice introduction to the various strategies that you could pick from.

As for the note on adding unnecessary overhead to the database - I wouldn't worry about it just yet.  EF is generally about getting a product built more rapidly and as it has to cope with a more general case, doesn't always produce the most efficient SQL. If the performance is a problem after your application is built, working and correct you can revisit and fix up the most inefficient stuff then.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a person overlap between the mentioned tables, then yes, you should separate them out into a `Persons` table.

If you are only tracking what role each `Person` has (i.e. `Student` vs. `Teacher` etc) then you might consider just having the following three tables: `Persons`, `Roles`, and a bridge table `PersonRoles`.

On the other hand, if each role has it's own unique fields, then you should carry on as you are and leave each of these tables separate with a foreign key of `PersonID`.

Answer (score 0):

If the `attributes` (i.e. First Name, Last Name, Gender etc) of these `entities` (i.e. Students, Teachers, Admins and Personnel) are exactly the same then you could just make a single table for all the entities with `PersonType` or `Role` attribute added to distinguish  each person's role. However, if the entities has a lot of different attributes then it would be better that you create separate tables otherwise you will have `normalization` problem.

Answer (score -2):

Yes that is a very bad way of structuring a DB. The DB structure should be designed based on the Normalizations.

Please check the normalization forms.

U should avoid the duplicate data as much as possible, else the queries will become slower.

And the main problem is when u r trying to get data that is associated with more than one or two tables.